# Mocked method still calls the real method

Tags: java, junit, easymock

I have mocked the request and the response using the *easymock*, but its still going through each line in the request method and getting exception.

Eg:

```
public class helper{

public String getCB(){
  Response response = serviceImpl.getDefaultMethod(request);
  return response.getString();
}
```

Test:

```
expect(MockServiceImpl.getDefaultMethod(mockRequest)).andReturn(mockResponse);
```

Getting an exception, Its going inside the `getDefaultMethod()`.

I'm not understanding why its going through the code in that method. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: please add  [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)s for both, the production code and the test.

Comment: I tried with the posted example, it didn't worked for me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60500323/i-am-mocking-the-method-but-in-the-test-when-i-called-the-method-debugger-going

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60500323/i-am-mocking-the-method-but-in-the-test-when-i-called-the-method-debugger-going

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK easymock is not able to mock static method calls.

You should move the line

> ```
> Response response = ServiceImpl.getDefaultMethod(request);
> ```

out of the method and mock `request`.

The other approach was to use PowerMock, but IMHO that's a surrender to bad design.

Comment: getDefaultMethod is not static

Comment: *"getDefaultMethod is not static"* but you use a static access (before the edit and in your test example still)

Answer (score 0):

If the method is not static and not final, it should work.

If it doesn't, it means you are not calling this method on a mock but on an real instance of the class. Showing us the mock creation and injection will help us confirm that.